# Salvando os dados de imagem de json/web-service para sqlite no iphone

Tags: json, ios, objective-c, imagem, sqlite3

Oi!

Gostaria de saber se voce pode me ajudar, estou tentando salvar uma imagem em um banco sqlite, no iphone. Mas não estou conseguindo.
 Explicando brevemente como funciona...

O app se conecta ao servidor e recebe os dados usando Json. Depois de recebido, os dados são salvos no sqlite, para disponibilizar os dados para o usuario quando o iphone estiver offline(sem conexão com a internet).

Então teria que passar a imagem, vinda do Json para um campo da tabela no sqlite.

Alguem poderia ajudar!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até é possível salvar a imagem no banco, mas não é usual. Geralmente o que se faz é salvar a imagem no sandbox da aplicação (área do disco a qual só a app tem acesso). O que você precisará guardar, usando um banco de dados por exemplo, é o caminho da imagem.

Você pode baixar a imagem da seguinte maneira:

```
- (UIImage *)loadImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Então, caso deseje salvar o objeto `UIImage` no disco, converta-o para `NSData`:

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {

    NSData *imageData;
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        extension = @"png";
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        extension = @"jpg";
    }

    if (imageData) {
        NSString *imagePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, extension]];
        [imageData writeToFile:imagePath options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ola! Rafael!! 

Obrigado pela ajuda, eu consegui resolver este problema, fazendo quase oq vc fez ai em cima: Eu recebi a imagem vindo de um webservice (uando json), e armazeneri em um NSString, depois converti esse NSString para NSData... e logo depois esse NSData é inserido no banco usando a função: sqlite3_bind_blob!!

 Mas obrigado assim mesmo! E seu código já esta aqui guardado para futuras consultas!!!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Para ajudar usuários que venham a ter a mesma dúvida, aceite a resposta ou coloque a sua solução para o problema. Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer